# Changing position of button label in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, ios-4.2

I'm just wondering if anyone could help me change the position of a button label for a button that I've made with code.

Thanks a lot,

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean UIButton, look at UIButton's titleEdgeInsets property.

Answer (score 2):

So the *button label* is an instance of UILabel, isn't it ?? Set the position of that label by setting the frame to it with respect to the UIButton frame.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(3, 20, w, h)];
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, w, h)];
[titleLabel setText:@"TITLE"];
[button addSubview:titleLabel];
[self.view addSubview:button];
[titleLabel release];
```

I hard coded the x and y positions of the button as well as for the label. You set some other value's and place the label in the respective position where ever you want.

If you want to set only the text position of that label you can do it like this:

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(3, 20, w, h)];
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
    [titleLabel setText:@"TITLE"];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];//(UITextAlignmentRight/UITextAlignmentLeft)
    [button addSubview:titleLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [titleLabel release];
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,32);
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(BackBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 32)];
    backButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backButtonView.bounds, -1, -4);
    [backButtonView addSubview:button];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
    //barButtonItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6, 20, 30, 0);

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```